# Play Modular Development: sub projects chicken and the egg

Tags: configuration, module, routes, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play 2.x sub projects are the way to build modular applications, looks great.

Now, getting into the nitty gritty some issues become clear:

```
1) Cyclical dependencies not possible (A can depend on B, but B cannot depend on A)  
2) A child project cannot access a parent project  
3) Routing and Assets are isolated to each sub project
```

In my case I'd like to structure an application  as follows:

```
Main
Modules
-> Core
-> Model
-> Common
-> View
  -> Desktop
  -> Mobile
-> Controller
  -> admin
  -> account
  -> public
```

Now, let's say the admin controller receives a mobile request, but the user is not yet logged in. OK, we need to pull in `View > Mobile > views > login > index.scala.html`

Since controller sub projects depend on views (and not vice-versa), the view will have no access to the controller routes, which means something like `@form(action = admin.routes.auth)` won't work.

Could scrap view sub projects and store views under each individual controller sub project, but that looks like a recipe for massive template code duplication.

All is good with a basic core, model, main (assets, controllers, views) sub project setup, but when you need to support mobile and desktop interfaces, along with crud and front facing views, then it gets much more complex.

Sub projects start to look like the Holy Grail when you see the gargantuan build times resulting from a single routes file.

Implementing is another matter.